# How to search through html table rows?

Tags: c#, html, .net

Using Windows Forms and C#.
For example...

```
         <table id=tbl>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>HELLO</td>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BLAH BLAH</td>
            <td>YES</td>
            <td>TEST</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
```

I load the page using the WebBrowser Control. The page loads perfectly. 
The next thing I want to do is search through all the rows in the table and check if they contain a specific value ; for example in this instance YES.
If they contain it I want the row to be passed on to me so I can store it as string. 
But I want the row to be in HTML form. (containing the tags).

How can I accomplish this ?
Please help me.

Comment: You can use `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to easily parse the html.  For example, to get all of the TD elements, you can do this:

```
string value = @"         <table id=tbl>
              <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>HELLO</td>
                <td>YES</td>
                <td>TEST</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>BLAH BLAH</td>
                <td>YES</td>
                <td>TEST</td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
             </table>";

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(value);

var nodes = doc.GetElementbyId("tbl").SelectNodes("tbody/tr/td");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me a way through which I could get the table's html ?

Comment: Just use the `InnerHtml` property on the `GetElementById("tbl")` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ , its really simple way how to search in HTML files

Just include simple_html_dom.php to your file and then just follow this manual 
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

and your php code will looks like

```
$html = file_get_html('File.html');

foreach($html->find('td') as $element) 
   echo $element->text. '<br>';
```